# Use SharePoint Server Search 14 on one WFE or both?

Tags: 2010, search, sharepoint-server

I'm having a SharePoint Server 2010 installation and two WFEs'. As of today, only SharePoint Foundation Search V4 is running on Server 1, not SharePoint Server Search 14. From what I know, [it should be the SharePoint Server Search 14 that should be running](http://www.dotnetspider.com/forum/302919-What-Sharepoint-foundation-search-V4.aspx)?!

Given what I have, should I turn of the Foundation Search and go with the Server Search instead? And if I do should I use  SharePoint Server Search 14 on both WFEs' or just one. If I use it on one only - I may be a lot of load on that server, especially when performing a full crawl.

The option would be to use SharePoint Server Search 14 on both WFEs'? But what is best practice?

[image: Screenshot of local services with SharePoint Server Search 14 service highlighted]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the topology of your farm. 
The search service should be running on all of your Application Servers.

If only one of your WFE's is also an application sever, then the search service needs to run on that server only.